# Unable to parse rss content in string format and store it in arrayList of beans

Tags: java, string, parsing, arraylist, rss

I am having RSS string in my code which is pulled from the database. I need to parse each of the values and store in a ArrayList of Beans.  For example, all values in title, link and description should be stored in the arraylist.

This is my Bean class

```
public class RssBean {
String title;
String link;
String description;

public RssBean(String title,String link,String description)
{
    this.title=title;
    this.link  = link;
    this.description = description; 
}

public String getTitle(){
    return title;
}

public void setTitle(String title){
    this.title = title;
}

public String getLink(){
    return link;
}

public void setLink(String link){
    this.link = link;
}

public String getDesc(){
    return description;
}

public void setDesc(String  description){
    this.description=description;
} 
}
```

Main program goes this way -

```
import java.util.ArrayList;        
public class RssToList {
public static void main(String args[])
{   ArrayList<RssBean> list = new ArrayList<RssBean>(); 
    RssBean bean = new RssBean(null, null, null);

    String rss = "<rss version="+"\"2.0\"\">" + 
            "<channel>"+
    "<title>W3Schools Home Page</title>"+
    "<link>http://www.w3schools.com</link>"+
    "<description>Free web building tutorials</description>"+  
             "<item> "+
             "<title>RSS Tutorial</title>"+
             "<link>http://www.w3schools.com/rss</link>"+
              "<description>New RSS tutorial on W3Schools</description>"+
             "</item>"+
             "</channel>" +
              "</rss>";

for(int i=0;i<rss.length();i++)
{
    while(rss.startsWith("<item>") && rss.endsWith("</item>"))
    {
    //  bean.setTitle(rss.substring(rss.indexOf("<title>"),rss.lastIndexOf("</title>")));   
    //  bean.setLink(rss.substring(rss.indexOf("<link>"),rss.lastIndexOf("</link>")));
    //  bean.setDesc(rss.substring(rss.indexOf("<description>"),rss.lastIndexOf("</description>"))); 

        String title =  StringUtils.substringBetween(rss, "<title>", "</title>");
        String link = StringUtils.substringBetween(rss, "<link>", "</link>");
        String description = StringUtils.substringBetween(rss, "<description>", "</description>");

        bean.setTitle(title);
        bean.setLink(link);
        bean.setDesc(description);

        System.out.println(bean);
    } //end if

     //add the bean to list 
    list.add(bean);
}//end for   
}
}
```

I am not able to get the results, looks like my logic is completely wrong... I see program terminated. Can someone correct the above code and guide me to the result?

Comment: You are trying to parse XML -- use an XML parser (`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder` etc)

Comment: I didn't use XML parsers such as DOM or SAX because this is stored in the string format and not in URL format. Is it still possible to use XML parser in this case?

Comment: See my answer for how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to parse XML, use an XML parser (`javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder`).

If the input is already in a string, just instantiate an `org.xml.sax.InputSource` as a wrapper for the `String` and pass that to `DocumentBuilder#parse(InputSource is)`.  Assuming it's valid XML all the hard work is done and you can cherry-pick the data you want.

Comment: Jim, I have posted another question here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18583487/how-to-set-nodevalues-to-bean-and-add-to-arraylist-of-beans          Can you please help me make corrections in the code.. Looks like I almost got what I wanted, only a small problem.. some type mismatch I believe. It would be great help if you can check it and let me know your thoughts! Thanks for all your help!